# Is there a way to call a function in contextBridge, that won't be read in renderer.js, from main.js in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-vue

I hope you are having a good morning. I was wondering if there was a way to call a regular function in contextBridge in preload.js from main.js that will not be read by renderer.js. For example when wanting to call a regular function in contextBridge, not having to use ipcRenderer, you simply do `window.preloader.functionName()` in **renderer.js**.

I want to do the exact same thing except in **main.js**. I have tried doing  `win.webContents.functionName();` in **main.js**, however, I receive the error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘functionName’)`

Please let me know if you have a solution! Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll want to post some actual code to give us a sense of what you're trying to do. It's not clear from the snippets. The error indicates that `win` isn't defined, so where is `win` coming from?

Comment: You can't just send a message to the renderer via `yourWin.webContents.send("callFunction");` and then have your preload script intercept that message via `ipcRenderer.on("callFunction", () => functionName());`?

Comment: That was the way I did it! Thanks for the response!